# pylibpd in blender game engine

Tags: python, blender, puredata

Does anyone know how to implement pure data into blender using the pylibpd-library? I did try it myself but i only got this error when trying to import the module. Is it by any chance possible at all? I am using the mac version of blender 2.7.

```
Python script error - object 'Cube', controller 'Python':
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pd.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/"myusername"/Desktop/BlenderPylibpdTest/pylibpd.py", line 26, in <module>
    _pylibpd = swig_import_helper()
  File "/Users/"myusername"/Desktop/BlenderPylibpdTest/pylibpd.py", line 22, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pylibpd', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/Applications/Blender/blender.app/Contents/MacOS/2.70/python/lib/python3.3/imp.py", line 188, in load_module
return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/"myusername"/Desktop/BlenderPylibpdTest/_pylibpd.so, 2): Symbol not found: _PyInstance_Type
  Referenced from: /Users/"myusername"/Desktop/BlenderPylibpdTest/_pylibpd.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/"myusername"/Desktop/BlenderPylibpdTest/_pylibpd.so
```

Comment: Check out this puredata forum, it may be what your looking for. http://puredata.hurleur.com/sujet-5733-pure-data-osc-blender

Comment: I never tried it your way, but i have no idea what you really did. A more broad explanation for us would help. 
Where is the Source of the library? Where can we get it? 
Where did you import it in the blender gameengine,
how did you do that? 

And for us, who do not have the script but could help: What is in Line 1, 26, 22?...The Errormessage is good, but without Code not helpful enough.
Good Luck!